# Creating a world in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to create a world in Gazebo and am using the URDFs that come with ROS as samples to work from. I've created some walls and am currently working on creating some tables and counters, but i seem to be having a lot of issues with the collisions.

After dropping the model of the walls into Gazebo, I notice little by little it moves around. I'm guessing there are forces acting on it (i used the same settings as are in the "brics_rc_world.urdf" file): there is some inertial properties: mass=10, ixx=1, iyy=100, izz=1.

If i remove the  tag, the object floats around. If i remove the  tags - same deal.
I'd like to lay out all the walls and furniture (like kitchen counters and shelves) as though they are immobile. Once i start adding tables and chairs, that's a whole other story...

So, my question is:

1. Is there any way to nail certain things down to the floor and say these objects don't move - ever.
2. Is there more documentation on how to create worlds in Gazebo.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9475/creating-a-world-in-gazebo/) by [Michael Vin](https://answers.ros.org/users/310/michael-vin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. you can make things in Gazebo immovable by using the  tag. Set this to true in a model, and it won't be movable. Example: true
2. We are working on documentation for creating world files in Gazebo. Currently, the best method is to look at examples in the gazebo sources: roscd gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo/worlds

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 431 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4